# Can I set the priority of a MongoDB query so that batch/archiving operations are yielded to user requests?

Tags: mongodb, concurrency, locking

I have been using Mongo's map/reduce for some time and this blocks other operations since the JS engine in 2.0 took out a lock (or so I believe). I am just experimenting with the new aggregation framework in 2.2 and had hoped that since it's just reading it would not need to lock, but according to db.currentOps() it is locking.

So in relation to the new aggregation framework (and indeed with any MongoDB operation) I would like to know if it's possible to indicate a priority of a certain operation so that MongoDB can intelligently yield low priority operations (such as some background updates) to a time-sensitive high-priority operation?

Answer (score 1):

In this [doc](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/How+does+concurrency+work#Howdoesconcurrencywork-Operations) you can see it says Map Reduce "Allows substantial concurrent operation but exclusive to other javascript execution."

So this means that it already yields operation on the database. Plus mostly this is bounded to the map/reduce being a single threaded JavaScript operation.

But if you want make sure there is no locking you can write the output of Map Reduce to another database and then move the collection to the original database.

```
>use admin
>db.runCommand( {renameCollection: "mapreducedb.mycol", to: "appdb.mycol"} )
```

Same for the Aggregation Framework

**EDIT:** can't be used for the Aggregation framework (as of 2.2), as it does not have an {{$out}} operator to write to another database. But Aggregation operations are still safe to execute on the production/main database as Yielding of those operations will still occur.

Comment: Note that the Aggregation Framework doesn't have an [$out](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3253) operator as at MongoDB 2.2.0, so the tip of using a different output db only applies to MapReduce ;-).  The aggregation framework results are currently only returned inline.

Comment: I've been looking for an example of MapReduce with a different output DB specific, but am coming up blank. Can somebody point me in the right direction please?